# Paretochart module in Anaconda 1.6.9

Tags: python, anaconda

```
from paretochart import pareto
```

Running this code Jupyter give me:

```
ImportError: No module named paretochart
```

How can I solve this problem? I tried to install via terminal the paretochart package and it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in jupyter cell:

```
!python -m pip install paretochart
```